# What's the difference between LAYER_TYPE_NONE and LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE when animating view with hardware acceleration enabled

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

According to [Android develop guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), display lists will be created for hardware acceleartion view with LAYER_TYPE_NONE, while [hardware layer](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html) will be created for hardware acceleartion view with LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE. There is no need for redrawing view when applying rotation animaiton in either approach. So, what's the actual difference bewteen  LAYER_TYPE_NONE and LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE when animating view with hardware acceleration enabled？

Answer (score 6):

First the view will be redrawn if you are applying rotation animation.

Hardware layers(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE) are cached on the GPU, which makes certain operations during animation much faster. Simple transformations (translation, **rotation**, scaling and alpha) can be rendered quickly with layers.

**LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE** uses layers that take up GPU memory and obviously you don't want any memory leaks. Therefore, you should only use hardware layers when necessary, like during animations.

With **LAYER_TYPE_NONE**, you explicitly want to avoid hardware layer rendering  with hardware acceleration enabled.

For reference, read http://blog.danlew.net/2015/10/20/using-hardware-layers-to-improve-animation-performance/

Comment: According to [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), *Using display lists also benefits animation performance because setting specific properties, such as alpha or rotation, does not require invalidating the targeted view (it is done automatically).*

Comment: i guess for rotation, it invalidates itself, how can a change in view occur without redrawing the view?

Comment: It is quite possible if you only need rotate a view. The CPU draws displayList/ layer, GPU composites the layer/displayList with a specified affine matrix which contains translate, rotate, scale to its parent.